# Twilio: How to get the call record mp3 file?

Tags: twilio, call-recording

I am using [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-call-logs-csharp) API for getting Twilio call logs. Some of the calls are recorded, so I need to get the corresponding mp3 file. Under the `subresource_uris` section I found `recordings`, but it is a .json file.

How can I get the mp3 file link of call records? I am using c# codes.

Answer (score 1):

The `.json` is to retrieve the metadata.

If you want to retrieve the actual recording leave out the `.json` (will deliver `.wav`) or add a `.mp3`, i.e. `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXX.../Recordings/REXXXXX....mp3`.

See also the Twilio documentation "[Fetch a recording media file](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#fetch-a-recording-media-file)".

---

The Twilio media URLs should be public by default, see "[Fetch a Recording resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#fetch-a-recording-resource)":

> Because the URLs that host individual recordings are useful for many external applications, they are public and do not require HTTP Basic Auth to access.

However you can turn on HTTP Basic Auth via the [settings](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings):

[image]

Comment: I have tried this: replaces .json with .mp3 and added `https://api.twilio.com` before the current link. But when I try to click on that link the below screen is continuously showing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrCJW.png

Comment: You might have enabled HTTP Basic Auth (the login box you're seeing is HTTP Basic Auth), check your [settings](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings) and make sure that it's set to `Disabled`. I've updated the answer with some more information.

Comment: I tried to play the call record audio with enable and disable conditions for HTTP Basic Auth. In both cases, I am getting the same dialog box. Sorry for the late response. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrCJW.png

Comment: Only for few of my call log has the recording. But for all items the recording URL is available. Is there any way to find the call records are available or not from the call log response?