# Twilio: Issue with call record mp3 file in call logs

Tags: twilio, call-recording

I'm using this [API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-call-logs-csharp) for getting the Twilio call logs. I want the recording for the corresponding call as an mp3 file. We are accessing recording URLs from the `recordings` under `subresource_uris` but that is the .json file. As per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398055/twilio-how-to-get-the-call-record-mp3-file), we replaced .json with .mp3 and added https://api.twilio.com at the beginning. If we try to play the recording it is not playing.

Currently, the recording URL is available for all call logs but only a few of the calls have enabled the call record. So how we can distinguish a call is recorded or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From what I can tell, you are trying to access recording files for calls in C#. You can get a list of recordings for a call by requesting the [call's recording resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording?code-sample=code-get-all-recordings-for-a-given-call&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x):

```cs
string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var recordings = RecordingResource.Read(
  callSid: "CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  limit: 20
);

// print out each recording's URI
foreach(var record in recordings)
{
  Console.WriteLine(record.Uri);
}
```

If you run the above with a call Sid that has recordings then you will see the URIs of the recording's printed out. They will look like:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings/REXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json
```

This is the URI you should take, prefix with `https://api.twilio.com` and change the extension from `.json` to `.mp3` in order to get the recording file. So, for the above example, requesting:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings/REXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3
```

So, if you use the API to get the call logs to get the Call SIDs, then call on each call's recordings resource you can then get the list of recordings and construct the URI to download each recording audio file.

Comment: What status do we need to keep for Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs? Is it enable or disable? On the below thread's answer, yvesonline suggested enable it, but on the comments under answer, he is telling to disable it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398055/twilio-how-to-get-the-call-record-mp3-file

Comment: If you want to Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs then you should enable the setting in your console.

Comment: I tried to play the call record audio with enable and disable conditions for HTTP Basic Auth. In both cases, I am getting the same dialog box. i.stack.imgur.com/VrCJW.png. I want the audio URL that can be played from chrome too.

Comment: Can you try disabling http auth on media urls, then making a new recording, then trying to access that in the browser? My suspicion here is that the HTTP auth is not applied to existing recordings so that you don't unintentionally expose previously protected recordings.

Comment: We will test it and let you know. Currently, we are getting URLs for all the calls how can I distinguish which call log actually have recorded.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean there. You can request recordings by Call Sid, as in my answer above, and if a call does not have recordings it will return an empty list. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: We tried to fetch the all call logs and call log by Sid, on both cases we are getting urls for all call logs(for calls which don't have a recording). We are fetching like this: `record.SubresourceUris["recordings"]`, is that method wrong?

Comment: When you get a Call Sid you can use the method from my answer above to fetch the recordings. If a call doesn't have any recordings it won't return any when you make that request, but if it does, you will get a list of recording resources.

Comment: I am listing the entire call logs using the below API. If I add the record fetching UI inside of that, it will take more time to load all call logs. Because on UI I need to show an audio option if a call has recorded files. Is there any way to get the recorded mp3 files details from the below API? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-call-logs-csharp

Comment: No, you need to get the recording files from the API call I described above. If you need to show the results in a list with the recordings too, I would recommend you cache the API calls or fetch and store the recording URLs some other way so that you don't have to make multiple API calls from the UI.