# Xamarin forms: Issue while playing recorded calls in Twilio

Tags: xamarin.forms, twilio

I'm using Twilio API for getting the Twilio call logs. I want the recording for the corresponding call in .mp3 format. We are accessing recording URLs, but that is the .json format, so we replaced .json with .mp3 and added https://api.twilio.com at the beginning using the following codes

```
    var recordings = RecordingResource.Read(
                callSid: sid,
                limit: 1
    );, 
    foreach (var item in recordings)
    {
        recordUrl = "https://api.twilio.com" + item.Uri.Replace(".json", ".mp3");
    }
```

But we can't play the recorded call.

We doubt in Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs currently its status is Enabled. If we disable it, is there any security issue? Are we able to play the audio after disabling it? What should Enforce HTTP Auth status on Media URLs if we access Twilio from the mobile app?

Comment: How are you trying to play the calls?  What errors or exceptions are you getting?  Are you sure you are using the correct url?

Comment: @Jason There is no error expected. We are trying to play using mm:VideoView, and the URL given is correct as per this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282968/twilio-issue-with-call-record-mp3-file-in-call-logs

Comment: have you tried playing the urls from desktop audio tool?  What if you download the files locally before playing them - does that work?

Comment: @Jason We tried to play it from Chrome, but it shows the same dialog box again and again  i.stack.imgur.com/VrCJW.png.

Comment: its asking you to authenticate.  Have you tried disabling "Enforce HTTP Auth" as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Jason Yes, But disabling "Enforce HTTP Auth" is also giving the same dialog box.

Comment: It sounds like you probably need to use auth to download the recordings locally before playing them, or use a media player that supports using auth credentials.  Or you could ask Twilio if there is a way to disable auth

Comment: @Jason Is there any way to download the MP3 File?

Comment: Yes, use HttpClient.  There are hundreds of existing questions about downloading a file in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the "Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs" option so you can use the URL to access the file without authentication.

When the "Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs" option is disabled, any person who has the Account SID and the Recording SID will be able to access the .mp3 file. On the other hand, when the option is enabled, you might have to use your Account SID and Auth Token to get access to the recording file.

If you need to keep your recordings secure with the HTTP basic auth, I suggest enable the "Enforce HTTP Auth on Media URLs" option and download the .mp3 file making an HTTP request; here is a code example of how to make the request.

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RestSharp.Extensions;

var client = new RestClient("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3​");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("Account_SID", "Token_Auth");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs("/your_path/recording_file.mp3");
```